# XML to Powershell Hashtable

Tags: xml, powershell, merge

```
<Test>
    <TLC>FWE</TLC>
    <Crew3LC>KMU</Crew3LC>
    <MyText>Hello World</MyText>
</Test>
```

Hello there,

above you see me .xml with the name "test.xml". Down below you see my powershell beginnings.

What I want do to is the following, but I don't know where exactly to begin.

I want to retrieve the data from the .xml file and save the values into my hashtable. The hashtable itself is more like a template, which needs to be filled.

The XML has got the same naming like the hashtable TLC = TLC etc, but I need the Value from the XML in my hashtable.

I would do it with foreach and a -matching operator and my filtered selections (Hashkey, XML Name, XML Name Value).

Matching the Hashkey with XML Name and if $true save XML.Name.Value to Hashtable.

I Hope you get my point... I tried some of my knowledge but everything faild so far.

My you guys could help me?!

```
# XML Path
$XMLSource = "C:\Test\Test.xml"

# Tempalte Hashtable
$XMLTemplatevalues = @{

    TLC      = 'TLC'
    Crew3LC  = 'Crew3LC'
    MyText   = 'MyText'

}

# Get XML Content
[xml]$GetXMLContent = Get-Content $XMLSource

#HashKey
$XMLTemplatevalues.Keys

#XML Name
$GetXMLContent.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Name

#XML Name - Value
$GetXMLContent.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.'#text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution that works with simple documents such as the one in your question (PSv4+):

```
$xmlDoc = [xml] (Get-Content -Raw "C:\Test\Test.xml")

# Initialize the results hashtable; make it ordered to preserve 
# input element order.
$ht = [ordered] @{}  

# Loop over all child elements of <Test> and create matching
# hashtable entries.
$xmlDoc.Test.ChildNodes.ForEach({ $ht[$_.Name] = $_.InnerText })

# Output the resulting hashtable.
$ht
```

With your sample document this yields:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
TLC                            FWE                                                                                                                                                  
Crew3LC                        KMU                                                                                                                                                  
MyText                         Hello World
```